# psexec windows 10 version 1709

Tags: windows-10

На всех ноутбуках которые обновились до Windows 10 version 1709
я не могу получить администраторские права, командой:

> psexec -u Administrator -p passwd powershell

Окно консоли открывается и значение переменной %USERNAME% - Administrator
Но если я пытаюсь выполнить какую нибудь команду требующую администраторских полномочий я получаю ошибку: Access Denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была не в psexec, а в том, что после обновления встроенная учетная запись администратора не получала повышенных привилегий. В реестре надо было изменить:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
FilterAdministratorToken 1 -> 0